# looping and inserting values into a table in mysql

Tags: mysql, arrays

Hi I have two arrays as input. I want to insert into a table using loop.
This is what I have tried.

```
simple_loop:LOOP

SET i = i + 1;
     simples_loop:LOOP
     SET j = j + 1;
     INSERT INTO ROLE_PRIVILEGE_BRIDGE (ROLE_ID,PRIVILEGE_ID,VALUE)
        VALUES(V_ROLE_FK,p_privilege_fk(i),p_values(j));
     END LOOP simples_loop;
END LOOP simple_loop;
```

This is just the portion of the procedure I have written. When executed the query an error showed up saying that ".p_privilege_fk() function does not exist.".
Can anyone please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
INSERT INTO ROLE_PRIVILEGE_BRIDGE (ROLE_ID,PRIVILEGE_ID,VALUE) 
    (SELECT V_ROLE_FK, p_privilege_fk, p_privilege_fk FROM firstTable)
```

Comment: `INSERT INTO ROLE_PRIVILEGE_BRIDGE (ROLE_ID,PRIVILEGE_ID,VALUE)
SELECT V_ROLE_FK, p_privilege_fk, p_privilege_fk FROM firstTable`