# Combining tables with identical columns in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am trying to replicate a scenario given by this question [Combine 2 tables with identical columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20386965/combine-2-tables-with-identical-columns) but I'm running into some serious problems. The setup is bascially this. I have two tables with identical columns but different content.

```
MASTER TABLE
    +----------------+---------------+----------------+--------------------------------------+
    | VOTE_CANDIDATE | SURPLUS_RATIO | ORIGINAL_VOTES | SURPLUS_REDISTRIBUTION_TO_CANDIDATES |
    +----------------+---------------+----------------+--------------------------------------+
    |              1 |         0.125 |              8 |                                   -1 |
    |              2 |         0.125 |              1 |                                   -1 |
    |              3 |         0.125 |              2 |                                   -1 |
    |              4 |         0.125 |              4 |                                   -1 |
    |              5 |         0.125 |              2 |                                   -1 |
    |              6 |         0.125 |              3 |                                   -1 |
    +----------------+---------------+----------------+--------------------------------------+

SLAVE TABLE
    +----------------+---------------+----------------+--------------------------------------+
    | VOTE_CANDIDATE | SURPLUS_RATIO | ORIGINAL_VOTES | SURPLUS_REDISTRIBUTION_TO_CANDIDATES |
    +----------------+---------------+----------------+--------------------------------------+
    |              2 |         0.125 |              1 |                                0.125 |
    |              3 |         0.125 |              2 |                                 0.25 |
    |              4 |         0.125 |              4 |                                  0.5 |
    |              5 |         0.125 |              2 |                                 0.25 |
    +----------------+---------------+----------------+--------------------------------------+
```

I want to combine them into one table, i.e. replace SURPLUS_REDISTRIBUTION_TO_CANDIDATES on rows 2,3,4,5 MASTER TABLE with corresponding rows from SLAVE TABLE. I have managed to work it down to this (the last row is excluded for some reason - i don't know why.)

```
COMBINED TABLE
    +----------------+---------------+----------------+--------------------------------------+
    | VOTE_CANDIDATE | SURPLUS_RATIO | ORIGINAL_VOTES | SURPLUS_REDISTRIBUTION_TO_CANDIDATES |
    +----------------+---------------+----------------+--------------------------------------+
    |              1 |         0.125 |            120 |                                   -1 |
    |              2 |         0.125 |              1 |                                0.125 |
    |              3 |         0.125 |              2 |                                 0.25 |
    |              4 |         0.125 |              4 |                                  0.5 |
    |              5 |         0.125 |              2 |                                 0.25 |
    +----------------+---------------+----------------+--------------------------------------+
```

This is pretty close to what I want though ORIGINAL_VOTES on row 1 should be 8 - not 120. It seems as the query summarizes ALL votes instead of the ones where vote_order = 1? **Why?**
More over - how do I ensure that the last row (6) isn't removed from the result?

My query is quite nasty, but it looks like this:

```
SELECT vote_candidate, (
  SELECT (
    (MAX(votes_above_the_threshold) - (
      SELECT FLOOR((COUNT(*) / (2 + 1)) + 1) threshold
      FROM votes
    )) / MAX(votes_above_the_threshold)
  ) ratio
  FROM (
    SELECT vote_candidate vote_candidate, COUNT(*) votes_above_the_threshold
    FROM vote_orders
    WHERE vote_order = 1
    GROUP BY vote_candidate
    HAVING votes_above_the_threshold >= (
      SELECT FLOOR((COUNT(*) / (2 + 1)) + 1) threshold
      FROM votes
    )
  ) t
  WHERE votes_above_the_threshold = (
    SELECT MAX(votes_above_the_threshold)
    FROM vote_orders
  )
) surplus_ratio, COUNT(*) original_votes, CASE 
  WHEN (
    SELECT MAX(votes_above_the_threshold) votes
    FROM (
      SELECT vote_candidate vote_candidate, COUNT(*) votes_above_the_threshold
        FROM vote_orders
        WHERE vote_order = 1
        GROUP BY vote_candidate
        HAVING votes_above_the_threshold >= (
          SELECT FLOOR((COUNT(*) / (2 + 1)) + 1) threshold
          FROM votes
        )
      ) t
      WHERE votes_above_the_threshold = (
        SELECT MAX(votes_above_the_threshold)
        FROM vote_orders
      )
    ) > (
      SELECT FLOOR((COUNT(*) / (2 + 1)) + 1) threshold
      FROM votes
    )
  THEN (
      SELECT FLOOR((COUNT(*) / (2 + 1)) + 1) threshold
      FROM votes
    ) - (SELECT MAX(votes_above_the_threshold) votes
    FROM (
      SELECT vote_candidate vote_candidate, COUNT(*) votes_above_the_threshold
        FROM vote_orders
        WHERE vote_order = 1
        GROUP BY vote_candidate
        HAVING votes_above_the_threshold >= (
          SELECT FLOOR((COUNT(*) / (2 + 1)) + 1) threshold
          FROM votes
        )
      ) t
      WHERE votes_above_the_threshold = (
        SELECT MAX(votes_above_the_threshold)
        FROM vote_orders
      )
    )
  ELSE 0
END surplus_redistribution_to_candidates
FROM vote_orders
UNION
SELECT vote_candidate, (
  SELECT (
    (MAX(votes_above_the_threshold) - (
      SELECT FLOOR((COUNT(*) / (2 + 1)) + 1) threshold
      FROM votes
    )) / MAX(votes_above_the_threshold)
  ) ratio
  FROM (
    SELECT vote_candidate vote_candidate, COUNT(*) votes_above_the_threshold
    FROM vote_orders
    WHERE vote_order = 1
    GROUP BY vote_candidate
    HAVING votes_above_the_threshold >= (
      SELECT FLOOR((COUNT(*) / (2 + 1)) + 1) threshold
      FROM votes
    )
  ) t
  WHERE votes_above_the_threshold = (
    SELECT MAX(votes_above_the_threshold)
    FROM vote_orders
  )
) surplus_ratio, COUNT(*) original_votes, (
  ROUND((COUNT(*) * (
    SELECT (
      (MAX(votes_above_the_threshold) - (
        SELECT FLOOR((COUNT(*) / (2 + 1)) + 1) threshold
        FROM votes
      )) / MAX(votes_above_the_threshold)
    ) ratio
    FROM (
      SELECT vote_candidate vote_candidate, COUNT(*) votes_above_the_threshold
      FROM vote_orders
      WHERE vote_order = 1
      GROUP BY vote_candidate
      HAVING votes_above_the_threshold >= (
        SELECT FLOOR((COUNT(*) / (2 + 1)) + 1) threshold
        FROM votes
      )
    ) t
    WHERE votes_above_the_threshold = (
      SELECT MAX(votes_above_the_threshold)
      FROM vote_orders
    )
  )), 3)
) surplus_redistribution_to_candidates
FROM vote_orders b
WHERE vote_order = 1
AND vote_candidate IN ((
  SELECT vote_candidate
  FROM vote_orders a
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT vote_id, MIN(vote_order) AS min_vote_order
    FROM vote_orders
    WHERE vote_candidate NOT IN ((
      SELECT vote_candidate
      FROM (
        SELECT vote_candidate vote_candidate, COUNT(*) votes_above_the_threshold
        FROM vote_orders
        WHERE vote_order = 1
        GROUP BY vote_candidate
        HAVING (
          votes_above_the_threshold >= (
            SELECT FLOOR((COUNT(*) / (2 + 1)) + 1) threshold
            FROM votes
          )
          OR (
            votes_above_the_threshold >= (
              SELECT FLOOR((COUNT(*) / (2 + 1)) + 1) threshold
              FROM votes
            )
            AND votes_above_the_threshold = 0
          )
          OR (
            votes_above_the_threshold = 0
          )
        )
      ) t
    ))
    GROUP BY vote_id
  ) b
  ON a.vote_id = b.vote_id
  AND a.vote_order = b.min_vote_order
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT vote_id
    FROM vote_orders
    WHERE vote_candidate = (
      SELECT vote_candidate
      FROM (
        SELECT vote_candidate vote_candidate, COUNT(*) votes_above_the_threshold
        FROM vote_orders
        WHERE vote_order = 1
        GROUP BY vote_candidate
        HAVING votes_above_the_threshold >= (
          SELECT FLOOR((COUNT(*) / (2 + 1)) + 1) threshold
          FROM votes
        )
      ) t
      WHERE votes_above_the_threshold >= (
        SELECT MAX(votes_above_the_threshold)
        FROM vote_orders
      )
    )
    AND vote_order = 1
  ) c
  ON a.vote_id = c.vote_id
  GROUP BY vote_candidate
))
GROUP BY vote_candidate;
```

I am running this on MySQL 5.0.83.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I need to clarify! The only column pulled straight from the table is 'vote_candidate'. All other columns are renamed due to the manipulation I do before rendering them on screen.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am grossly misunderstanding your question, I think you are grossly over-complicating it.  Is this what you are looking for? (obviously, change the column/table names to be what you need)

```
UPDATE Master m
JOIN Slave s ON m.VOTE_CANDIDATE = s.VOTE_CANDIDATE
SET m.SURPLUS_REDIST = s.SURPLUS_REDIST
```

EDIT: 
This makes a few assumptions, but will display those changes without actually performing the update.  Another way would be to copy the master table into a temp table and update the temp table, then SELECT * from it.

```
SELECT * FROM Master m
WHERE VOTE_CANDIDATE NOT IN (
    SELECT VOTE_CANDIDATE FROM Slave
)
UNION 
SELECT * FROM Slave
```

Comment: Yeah, I do believe it is over-complicated - I'm a newbie to database queries. :) At this point I don't want to store any data in the MASTER table - I just want to join the two tables together. In the next step I'll update all information but for now I just want to se the combined information.

Comment: @KristoferGisslén careful saying "join the two tables together".  `JOIN` has a special meaning in mysql that will be easily mis-interpreted.  So are you looking to have one table with (in this instance) 10 rows, which shows the combined data of both tables?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I'll remember that. No, I still want 6 rows as in MASTER TABLE but the column SURPLUS_REDISTRIBUTION_TO_CANDIDATES on rows 2-5 should be updated to the corresponding information from SLAVE TABLE.

Comment: @KristoferGisslén then I think the code I provided will do that. IF it does not, please post an example table of what you want the end results to look like.  That way we can know without a doubt what it is you want.

Comment: Your code most definitely would do the trick. At the end of it your solution would be the solution I'd use, but the thing is I don't want to store any updated information in the table at this moment. I just want to combine the result and view it on the screen. My reason for this is that I need to validate other functionality before I update the table - and those functions are yet to be built. :) Therefore I don't want to mess with the original information in the MASTER TABLE.

Comment: @KristoferGisslén Updated my answer.  The second query should pull down every entry in the master table that does not have a corresponding key in the slave table, and then `UNION` it with everything in the slave table.  This makes a few assumptions so you might have to play with it, but see if it works for your needs