# Mysql insert into with multiple id from another table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 table,
first I retrieve all Ids like this:

```
select DISTINCT entity_id From table1
```

I want to create a bulk insert using entity_id and prevent duplicate if the entity_id have a specifique value in the colomn2:

example

```
    *********************************************
    *  ID   *  ENTITY_ID *  COLOMN2 *  value    *
    *********************************************
    *  1    *     230    *    20    *    1      *
    *  2    *     230    *   100    *    1      *
    *  3    *     280    *    20    *    0      *
    *  4    *     220    *    20    *    1      *
    *********************************************
    select DISTINCT entity_id From table1 // return : 230,280,220


    INSERT into table1 ('ENTITY_ID','COLOMN2','VALUE') VALUES([the select id],100,1) 
    WHERE COLOMN2<>100
```

or something like that?

the result need to be:

creating 2 insert... entity_id=220 and entity_id=280

with the colomn2=100 and value = 1

any idea ?

Comment: use a subquery in the second part  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20232947/looping-and-inserting-into-a-table-in-mysql/20232993#20232993

Comment: I think some information is missing here... You select unique entitity_ID's and then insert them into table1... based off of what data? from where? Not sure where the data for this decision comes from. Also "Colomn2" and "value" are terrible names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a subquery

```
INSERT INTO table1 ('ENTITY_ID','COLOMN2','VALUE')
(select DISTINCT entity_id ,100,1 FROM table2 WHERE column2<>100)
```

Comment: it's a good part of solution.. but I guess that we'll do a duplicate entity_id where column2 =100?

Comment: no because it's a distinct entity_id. or you can add WHERE column2<>100 to make sure

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you consider "duplicate" to mean BOTH "ENTITY_ID" and "COLOMN2" have the same value, i.e:

(50, 50)  & (50, 99) == not duplicate

(80, 42) & (99, 42) == not duplicate

(55, 66) & (55, 66) == duplicate

Can you create a compound unique key on your database?  Such as, for mysql:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX nodupes ON table1 (ENTITY_ID, COLOMN2);
```

You would then need to determine how to handle errors during the insert process.